# R 3.3.0 on Windows x64- trouble with subsetting

Tags: r, subset

I'am trying to subset a dataframe using the following code:

```
cr[cr$complete_cases >= 150, cr$corr]
```

and it returns the error below:

```
Error in x[j] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts.
```

complete_cases is a numeric column that ranges from 0 to 1095.

Comment: Just write `"corr"` not `cr$corr` in the second arg of `[ , ]`

Comment: It may also be worth a caution that `complete.cases` is an R function and would cause problems if you used that as a variable name.